# Ring/Field Extension and polynomial/series notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation

Let $R$ be a ring and $F$ be a field.

I know that $R[x]$ denotes the ring of polynomials with coefficients from $R$.

I know that $R(x)$ denotes the ring of rationals expressions with coefficients from $R$, formed by creating the field of fractions for $R[x]$.

I have also been taught $R[[x]]$ and $R((x))$ for the rings of formal power series and formal Laurent series (which is somehow related to the field of fractions for $R[[x]]$, I think), respectively.

But I notice that for $u$ an element of a field extension (or just a larger ring), $R[u]$ denotes the ring obtained by appending $u$ to $R$ (like the Gaussian integers, for example) and $F(u)$ denotes the "smallest field" (in the sense of inclusion) that includes both $F$ and $u$.

Is there a relationship between this notation? Is it all context based? Some clarification over this notation, as well as the relationship between these rings/fields and the field of fractions, would be really helpful, because I feel like there's a "big picture" idea I'm missing here.

Comment: Aside: one usually doesn't write $R(x)$ except in the special case that $R$ is a field.

Comment: For the sake of argument, let $R\langle x\rangle$ denote the polynomial ring over $R$, and for $R\subset L$ (where $R$ is a subring of $L$) and $u\in L$, let $R[u]$ denote the smallest subring of $L$ containing $R$ and $u$. Then if $L = R\langle x\rangle$, and $u = x$ (the indeterminate, i.e. the polynomial $(0,1,0,0 ....)$), then $R[u] = R\langle x\rangle$, in other words $R[x] = R\langle x\rangle$.

Comment: if $u$ is not algebraic in $R$, then $R[u]\cong R[x]$ and $F(u)\cong F(x)$.